# React hooks multi-inputs question, what does ({ ...state, [name]: !prevState.Red})); do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[image]

I really don't understand what lines 14-17 do? （Red is a checkbox value, its initial value is false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code calls `setState` by spreading the prior state into a new object, and adding one property, the `name`. The result is a new state with one modified property, without mutating the previous state.

For example, if `name` is `Red`:

```
({ ...state, [name]: !prevState.Red })
```

is equivalent to

```
({ ...state, Red: !prevState.Red })
```

And since the `state` only has one other property, `input`, the above is equivalent to:

```
({ input: state.input, Red: !prevState.Red })
```

But this is *not how one should use `useState`*. Use separate state variables instead:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState('');
const [red, setRed] = useState(false);
// ...
if (name === 'Red') {
  setRed(!red);
} else {
  setInput(value)
}
```

That approach makes the code much easier to read and understand. Functional component state should almost never look the same as class component state.